# Is it safe to send an address of a parameter?

Tags: c, function, arguments, parameter-passing

Consider the following code snippet:

```
void read_write(unsigned* ptr, bool r_or_w) {
    if (r_or_w) {
        *ptr = read_from_device_register();
    } else {
        write_to_device_register(*ptr);
    }
}

unsigned read(void) {
    unsigned data = 0;
    read_write(&data, 1);
    return data;
}

void write(unsigned data) {
    read_write(&data, 0); // <--- sending address of received argument
}
```

Specifically, consider the fact that `void write(unsigned data)` sends a pointer to a value that it has received as argument.

Comparing to:

```
void write(unsigned w_data) {
    unsigned data = w_data;
    read_write(&data, 0); // <--- sending address of local variable
}
```

In both cases `data` is stored on the stack, only that in the first case `data` is stored on the call-frame of the caller, rather than in the callee as a local variable. Is it safe? are there any pitfalls? How common is it, if at all?

Comment: On title changes: The parameter (a *variable*) in the function has a name; the argument (a *value*) is supplied when the function is originally called.

Comment: Should `read`be `read_from_device_register`? And likewise for `write`

Comment: @4386427 This snippet was taken from actual code where in practice `read_write(unsigned* ptr, bool r_or_w)` does some more logic/processing before actually reading from/writing to the device. 
We didn't want to duplicate this logic.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, this code doesn't make much sense if it's supposed to be actual hardware-related programming.

Comment: like I said - in reality `read_write()` contains some logic/processing that we don't want to duplicate for read and write, and the code looks totally different. The snippet is just there to convey an idea

Comment: To send an address, where to?

Comment: Do you think whe will guess what do `read_write()` does?

Comment: you are welcome to guess if you like, though as I explained several times already it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> only that in the first case data is stored on the call-frame of the caller, rather than in the callee as a local variable.

Actually no, the way you've declared `w_data`, it will be copied by value into the function. At the point that `write()` is executing, it "owns" `w_data` in the sense that `w_data` is part of its scope. In fact with most ABIs, the first 3 or 4 arguments to a function are passed in hardware registers, not on the stack. In order to pass a memory location to `read_write()`, the compiler will have to first create an entry in the function's stack frame, store the value of the register in this entry, and pass the address of that entry to `read_write()`.

> Is it safe? are there any pitfalls?

Yes it's safe. There are always pitfalls with passing addresses to automatic variables, but these are all wrapped up in having a complete understanding of the scope of the value and how it's going to be used. For example imagine that the `read_write()` function was implemented using a DMA to the "device_register". This could be an asynchronous call, in which case the `w_data` variable would go out of scope before the operation finished. The effects would be indeterminate.

> How common is it, if at all?

Extremely common in low level software applications.

Answer (score 3):

There's no issue with lifetime here, as long as `read_write` doesn't store the pointer somewhere where it can outlive the pointee `data` from the `write` frame. As such, this is safe from the standpoint of program correctness. In fact, there's no difference between the two options as given -- an incoming parameter's address can be taken just like the address of a local variable can be taken. As for concerns about modifying variables in the frame of `write`'s caller, that's also irrelevant - `data` was passed by value.

However, pointer indirection for an unsigned integer can be a significant overhead if the function is called often or in a tight loop.

Further, from a design standpoint, this seems like an awkward design which is a bit hard to read; `write` delegates to `read_write` which ultimately delegates to `write_to_device_register`. This is a bit awkward to intuitively follow, and needlessly mixes the read and write paths together just to have them diverge again; this might be unsafe in the sense that the code is more brittle and more error prone to maintain as compared to a simpler design.

Answer (score 1):

The language specification doesn't say where parameters are stored; what you described about which stack frame holds the address is an implementation detail that's not part of the language. C doesn't even specify that there's a stack, although it's the typical implementation.

The location of the variable is not relevant in answering this question, just the lifetime of the variable. The lifetime of a function parameter is the same as local variables in the function's top-level block. You can pass the address to another function, and it's valid as long as it's only used before `write()` has returned. If the address is saved in some other data structure, using it after `write()` returns causes undefined behavior.

So there's no difference between using `&w_data` and `&data` as far as your question is concerned. A good compiler optimizer might even generate the same code for both versions.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely safe.

Even if `read_write(&data, 0);` used the pointer to change the value of `data` that change never impacts anything outside `void write(unsigned data){..}`. The `unsigned data` inside the function acts just as a local function variable except that it gets initialized by the value of the argument used when the function is called.

This is a simple but important feature in C: Arguments are always passed by value. A function can't change the value of the original argument. If the argument is a pointer, the function can change the value of the pointed-to-object but not the value of the argument itself.

Example:

```
void f1(int* p)
{
    *p = 42;
}

void f2(int n)
{
    printf("At start of f2 n is %d\n", n);
    f1(&n);
    printf("At end of f2 n is %d\n", n);
}

void f3(int* p)
{
    printf("At start of f3 *p is %d\n", *p);
    f2(*p);               
    printf("At end of f2 *p is %d\n", *p);
}
```

Calling the above chain like

```
int x = 17;
printf("Before f3 x is %d\n", x);
f3(&x);                          
printf("After f3 x is %d\n", x);
```

will produce (comments are mine):

```
Before f3 x is 17
At start of f3 *p is 17
At start of f2 n is 17
At end of f2 n is 42     // notice: f1 changed the value of n inside f2
At end of f3 *p is 17    // but when f2 returns the value of the original x is the same
After f3 x is 17         // Reason: x and n are to different variables
```